# How to save timeseries images with 50 time period

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to save images of close prices (PX_LAST) for every 50 days, with an increment of 1 day (e.g., chart 1 is from 0-50, chart 2 is from 1-51, etc.). Below is my code which keeps saving images for the entire dataset.

```
start_date = datetime. date(2001, 1, 3)
end_date = datetime. date(2020, 10, 16)
delta = datetime. timedelta(days=50)

while start_date <= end_date:
    last_date = start_date
    last_date+= delta
    for i in range(148):
        plt.plot(data.PX_LAST[start_date:last_date])
        plt.savefig("spy_image" + str(i) +".png")
    start_date += delta
```

sample dataset -

```
 Dates  PX_OPEN PX_HIGH PX_LOW  PX_LAST
2000-01-03  148.25  148.25  143.875 145.4375
2000-01-04  143.5313    144.0625    139.6406    139.75
2000-01-05  139.9375    141.5313    137.25  140.0
2000-01-06  139.625 141.5   137.75  137.75
2000-01-07  140.3125    145.75  140.0625    145.75
2000-01-10  146.25  146.9063    145.0313    146.25
2000-01-11  145.8125    146.0938    143.5   144.5
2000-01-12  144.5938    144.5938    142.875 143.0625
2000-01-13  144.4688    145.75  143.2813    145.0
2000-01-14  146.5313    147.4688    145.9688    146.9688
2000-01-18  145.3438    146.625 145.1875    145.8125
2000-01-19  145.3125    147.0   145.0   147.0
2000-01-20  146.9688    146.9688    143.8125    144.75
2000-01-21  145.5   145.5   144.0625    144.4375
2000-01-24  145.6563    145.8438    139.4063    140.3438
2000-01-25  140.5156    141.9375    139.0   141.9375
2000-01-26  141.0   141.5469    140.0938    140.8125
2000-01-27  141.8438    142.2188    138.125 140.25
2000-01-28  139.4375    140.0625    135.5313    135.875
2000-01-31  135.8125    139.6719    135.0   139.5625
2000-02-01  139.75  141.6875    138.5313    140.9375
2000-02-02  141.2813    142.25  140.375 141.0625
2000-02-03  140.875 143.25  140.0   143.1875
2000-02-04  143.1875    144.0   142.125 142.5938
2000-02-07  142.5625    142.7813    141.4375    142.375
2000-02-08  143.9688    144.5625    143.625 144.3125
2000-02-09  144.4688    144.4688    141.2656    141.2813
2000-02-10  141.625 142.5625    140.875 141.5625
2000-02-11  141.8438    141.9375    138.0313    138.6875
2000-02-14  139.7813    139.7813    138.3125    139.5
2000-02-15  139.25  141.2188    137.7969    141.0938
2000-02-16  140.375 140.9375    138.7969    139.0
2000-02-17  140.4375    140.4375    138.2188    138.2813
2000-02-18  138.875 138.875 134.625 135.3125
2000-02-22  135.1875    136.3438    133.5313    134.9688
2000-02-23  135.625 137.4688    134.5   136.5625
2000-02-24  136.6875    137.0313    133.0938    133.8125
2000-02-25  135.1875    136.7188    133.125 133.3281
2000-02-28  133.375 136.6875    132.7188    136.125
2000-02-29  136.0625    137.4375    135.75  137.4375
2000-03-01  137.625 139.0   137.2188    138.4375
2000-03-02  138.6875    139.125 137.3438    138.5313
2000-03-03  140.4375    141.7188    139.7188    141.125
2000-03-06  140.8125    141.3438    138.75  139.75
2000-03-07  140.0   140.1563    135.2188    137.0469
2000-03-08  136.4688    137.8438    135.0313    136.875
2000-03-09  137.25  140.875 136.125 140.875
2000-03-10  140.1875    142.0   139.5313    140.125
2000-03-13  136.6875    140.4688    136.5   138.5938
2000-03-14  139.2813    140.0938    136.1563    136.625
2000-03-15  136.875 140.4375    136.0625    139.8125
2000-03-16  141.625 146.8438    140.875 146.3438
2000-03-17  145.8125    148.0   145.4375    146.9375
2000-03-20  146.875 147.3438    144.7813    146.1875
2000-03-21  145.5313    149.75  144.5   149.1875
2000-03-22  149.5625    150.8438    148.6875    150.0938
2000-03-23  149.1563    153.4688    149.1563    152.6563
2000-03-24  152.875 155.75  151.7188    153.5625
2000-03-27  153.375 153.7813    151.8125    151.9375
2000-03-28  151.25  152.9844    150.5938    151.0625
2000-03-29  151.5625    152.4844    149.6563    151.2188
2000-03-30  150.1563    151.9219    147.125 148.6875
2000-03-31  149.625 152.3125    148.4375    150.375
2000-04-03  150.125 151.25  148.6875    151.25
2000-04-04  151.75  153.0   145.75  145.75
2000-04-05  147.875 150.8125    147.625 149.1875
2000-04-06  150.25  151.6875    149.0   150.4844
2000-04-07  151.5625    152.125 150.5   151.4375
2000-04-10  151.75  153.1094    150.3125    150.8438
2000-04-11  150.0   151.625 148.375 150.4063
2000-04-12  150.375 151.1563    146.1563    146.2813
2000-04-13  147.4688    148.1563    141.125 144.25
2000-04-14  142.625 142.8125    133.5   136.0
2000-04-17  135.1875    140.75  134.6875    140.75
2000-04-18  140.5625    144.4688    139.7813    144.4688
2000-04-19  144.5   145.125 142.5313    143.125
2000-04-20  143.5625    143.9375    142.375 143.8125
2000-04-24  141.5   143.3125    140.5   142.25
2000-04-25  144.625 148.1563    144.4375    148.1563
2000-04-26  147.9688    148.75  146.0   146.4844
2000-04-27  143.0   147.3438    143.0   146.0
2000-04-28  147.0   147.8594    145.0625    145.0938
2000-05-01  146.5625    148.4844    145.8438    147.0625
2000-05-02  145.5   147.125 144.125 144.125
2000-05-03  144.0   144.0   139.7813    140.75
2000-05-04  142.0   142.3594    140.75  141.8125
2000-05-05  141.0625    144.0   140.9375    143.5313
2000-05-08  142.75  143.375 141.8438    142.4531
2000-05-09  143.0625    143.4063    140.2656    141.3125
2000-05-10  140.5   140.9688    137.75  138.125
2000-05-11  140.125 141.5   139.125 141.2813
2000-05-12  141.8125    143.4688    141.625 142.8125
2000-05-15  142.75  145.6094    142.0   145.2813
2000-05-16  146.5625    147.7188    145.3125    146.6875
2000-05-17  145.6875    146.1875    144.4688    145.1563
2000-05-18  145.625 146.3125    143.375 143.375
2000-05-19  142.5625    143.2344    140.4063    141.125
2000-05-22  141.25  141.4688    137.0   140.0625
2000-05-23  140.4375    140.8125    137.5625    138.0
2000-05-24  138.0   140.6875    136.5   140.25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not specified how you want to deal with missing days but an approach close to yours could be like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.txt", delim_whitespace=True,  parse_dates=["Dates"])
df = df.sort_values("Dates")

startdt= df["Dates"].min()
enddt = df["Dates"].max()
delta = pd.Timedelta(20, unit="D")
delta1d = pd.Timedelta(1, unit="D")
i = 0

if startdt + delta > enddt:
    df.plot(x="Dates", y="PX_LAST", color="blue")
    plt.savefig(f"spy_image_{i:02d}.png")
    print(f"saved image {i:02d} covering period from {startdt:%Y-%m-%d} to {enddt:%Y-%m-%d}")
    plt.close()
else:    
    while startdt + delta <= enddt:
        temp = df[(df["Dates"] >= startdt) & (df["Dates"] <= startdt + delta)]
        temp.plot(x="Dates", y="PX_LAST", color="blue")
        plt.savefig(f"spy_image_{i:02d}.png")
        print(f"saved image {i:02d} covering period from {startdt:%Y-%m-%d} to {startdt+delta:%Y-%m-%d}")
        plt.close()
        i += 1
        startdt += delta1d
    
print("finished")
```

Comment: It seems there might be some error in code, upon executing with 50 periods, for a data with 5232 entries it outputs 7542 images.

Also, do you have any suggestion on how to deal with missing days?

Comment: For the second question: I would have sorted the df by Date, then plotted 50 consecutive rows. But this was not your question. As for the error - what can I say without your data? The code does what you asked it to do: counting stepwise by one day and storing the plot. If you have a range without any data, then a lot of empty plots will be generated. But this condition was not mentioned in your question. I assume you will find out that enddt - startdt for your data is 7492 days

Comment: Yes, the code does justice to the question asked. We are just looking for some input to fix the errors popping up. For the record, the date is 2000-01-03 to 2020-10-16.

After sorting values by dates, it still gives same amount of outputs, I guess, the weekends are bring counted as well, is there a way to only consider business days?

Comment: Pandas implemented the [business day datetime index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.bdate_range.html). One could generate a datetime series, then cycle through it to determine startdt and enddt with 50 day difference, and filter temp as shown above based on what is returned. But this will not take care of long periods without data.

Comment: Darn typo - I meant 7592 days, which is the number of days between your first and last date. So, as expected the code does what it is supposed to do. Assuming 5 days a week, that would lead to 5422 days - the missing 190 days in 20 years are probably bank holidays, meaning you don't have large gaps in your data. So, the abovementioned strategy might be implementable with a rolling frame of 35 rows. This will cover give and take three days the same time of 50 days in each graph without the need for fancy indexing.

Comment: thank you for your input, much appreciated.